# Receive data from websocket server (written in c#/vb.net) as image

Tags: c#, javascript, html, websocket

I'm kind of new in the websocket,
I learned the client-side code (in JavaScript) which is simple and easy,

but when I search the websocket server, the code is complicated (especially in c#),
and now I need a websocket server code (in c# or vb.net) that return some message to the client side (can be a string like "hello client") as an example and if possible with some explanation in the code,
and furthermore I also need some code for the server to send file (like .jpg) to the client side (if it's possible)

any idea? or if you have a good reference, I'm open to it,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of my projects, I'm using the [SuperWebSocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/) as .NET WebSocket server. There are also some examples included (I think also a simple echo example, which returns the received  string from a client).

I havn't sent an image yet, so I can't provide code for this problem.

If you also need a .NET WebSocket client, you can use [WebSocket4Net](http://websocket4net.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Do you have another example that simpler than the SuperWebSockets