# Make new simple websocket server with c#

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm very new to the websocket,
I'm trying to make a simple websocket server with c# from scratch,
anyone have a simple sample?? that I can understand easily?
Like just send string ("hello client") to the client side(HTML5 with JavaScript)
I'm using google chrome,
Thank you

Comment: If you're building it from scratch for fun, then please pay no attention to me when I say that Websockets are a built-in feature of ASP.net 4.5. See here http://www.paulbatum.com/2011/09/getting-started-with-websockets-in.html

Comment: Is this different from [your question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704633/receive-data-from-websocket-server-written-in-c-vb-net-as-image)?

Comment: The question was to use websocket for file transfer, apparently it's really complicated, so I try to ask for a basic one

Comment: Here is to make it clear, I would like to create a server with a basic functionality to send message/string to the client (in browser)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck) - very easy to start with and clean.

Comment: There is a console app project which shows you the implementation of a chat echo server. Very simple to use. You need to implement delegates for OnOpen, OnClose, OnMessage and can use Send to send data.

Comment: thanks! it worked! but I need to study the server first, since I need to modify it to send message to the client in string format (customizable)

Comment: unfortunately though, I can't make a server from scratch, and this Fleck is a hell lot of complex code, and need some time to understand, but the usage is very simple

Comment: There is a byte array and a string method - so you should be flexibale in your format - adding another send method should be really trivial.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install .NET Framework 4.5
2. [`using System.Net.WebSockets;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may also take a look at the [WebSocketRPC](http://websocket-rpc.net) library, which is simple enough.
Some code snippets are shown on the page.

Disclaimer: I am the author.